# My friend bought me a ticket on his card

Tags: air-travel, bookings, russia, nigeria

I'm traveling alone by Egyptair from Nigeria to Russia.The ticket was bought by my friend and by his DEBIT CARD. 
After I printed out the ticket, I saw in the rules that CREDIT CARD holder must be one of the travellers. And the company can remove the passenger from the flight if he does not show a card which tickets were paid for.
Does it work with DEBIT CARD too? Should I worry about this?

And another problem is that my friend mixed up my first and last name when he booked a ticket. I know this is not so critical, but in this situation can it also affect.
My friend says everything will be fine, but I'm not sure.[image]

Comment: Hanky Panky, but my friend his in Russia now not with me.

Comment: The type of the card isn't important. It's just that in some countries, association-based debit cards (Visa, Mastercard etc.) aren't common, so people are used to referring to all kinds of cards that support online payments as "credit cards".

Answer (score 5):

> Does it work with DEBIT CARD too? Should I worry about this?

Yes, you absolutely **should** worry about it. I would go to the airline office with him and get it resolved before going to the airport.

If an airline clearly communicates that the card holder must be one of the passengers then they will almost always verify this. The note that you see on the ticket will also be displayed on the check-in agent's computer.

As you have mentioned  in the comments that your friend is in Russia now and you are in Egypt, it may be hard to convince the airline without his presence.

In the worst case i would refund the ticket and buy it again on your card - even though its going to cost more. **It is still better than being denied boarding on an international flight.**

Comment: His in Russia now.

Comment: I would still go to EgyptAir's office Yesterday and explain the situation and get the note on the ticket updated for check-in agents.

Comment: @Mark ok I would also get clarification on the first/last name situation at the same time.

Comment: Hanky Panky, What happens if I check-in online? Maybe I can pass without risk?

Comment: @MarkOk What happens if you can't?

Comment: If they want to verify they will either prevent online check-in or prevent you from boarding until this is resolved. Your friend should call the airline and will probably need to visit their offices so they can make a mark in the file that this has been checked.

Comment: +1 Many airlines also allow the original holder of the card to fill a form, sign it, and send a copy of the back and front of the card to the airlines office in situations where the card owner cannot go to the airport.